# Partial Fraction Decomposition with Complex Number $\frac{1}{z^2 - 2i}$.

Tags: complex-numbers, partial-fractions

How do I decompose the fraction

> $$\dfrac{1}{z^2 - 2i}$$

into partial fractions? I understand how to do partial fraction decomposition with real numbers, but I am unsure of how to do it with complex numbers. I attempted to find examples online, but all examples are with real numbers -- not complex.

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to demonstrate this.

Comment: Factoring $\,z^2-2i\,$ would be a good starting point.

Comment: @dxiv Yes...that is precisely what I am asking...

Comment: You do it in the same way over any field. In the case of complex numbers, it is simpler because you have only *linear* irreducible factors.

Comment: @Bernard But $z^2 - 2i$ is quadratic -- not linear?

Comment: @ThePointer Use either the cartesian representation for $z\,$, or the polar one, and solve. Works fairly painlessly both ways.

Comment: $z^2-2i=(z+\sqrt{2i})(z-\sqrt{2i})=(z+1+i)(z-1-i)$. From here the process is identical to the decomposition of linear terms with real numbers

Comment: Yes, but it's not irreducible. That's the point of the *D'Alembert-Gauß*  theorem.

Comment: @Alex How did you get $(z + 1 + i)(z - 1 - i)$?

Comment: @ThePointer For the first equality, use difference of squares, $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. Next note that $\sqrt{2i}=\sqrt{2}(e^{i\pi/2})^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}=\sqrt{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)=1+i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $z^2-2i=(z+\sqrt{2i})(z-\sqrt{2i})$ and $\sqrt{2i}=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}=1+i$. To simplify, let $b=1+i$, then $$\frac{1}{z^2-2i}=\frac{1}{(z+b)(z-b)}$$ From here it actually doesn't matter if you regard $b$ as real or complex, the process to find the partial fractions is the same as long as the terms are linear in $z$. So we let $$\frac{1}{(z+b)(z-b)}=\frac{A}{z+b}+\frac{B}{z-b}$$ for some $A,B\in \mathbb C$. Adding the two fractions on the right hand side we get that $$A(z-b)+B(z+b)=1$$ and so $$A+B=0$$
$$-bA+bB=1$$ which has solution $$A=-\frac{1}{2b}$$ $$B=\frac 1{2b}$$
Plugging in the original $b=1+i$ we have that $$\frac{1}{2b}=\frac12\frac 1{(1+i)}\frac{(1-i)}{(1-i)}=\frac 14(1-i)$$ Therefore $$\frac{1}{z^2-2i}=-\frac{\frac 14(1-i)}{z+1+i}+\frac{\frac 14(1-i)}{z-1-i}.$$ As you can see the process for computing the partial fraction coefficients with complex rationals is equivalent to that of real numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the complete response. I did the calculations myself (with help from your post and those of others) and got $\dfrac{1}{(z - 1 - i)(z + 1 + i)} = \dfrac{1}{(z - 1 - i)(2 + 2i)} - \dfrac{1}{(z + 1 + i)(2 + 2i)}$.

Comment: For whatever reason, this answer absolutely captivates me! Stellar!

Answer (score 1):

the roots of $z^2 - 2i$ are $1+i$ and $-(1+i)$

$$  (1+i)^2 = 1^2 + 2 \cdot 1 \cdot i + i^2 = 1 + 2i - 1 = 2i  $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  either will work to find the square roots of $\,2i\,$:

- $\;\; 2i=(a+ib)^2 = a^2-b^2+2abi \implies a^2-b^2=0\,,\;2ab=2\,$
- $\;\; 2 e^{i \pi/2} = \left(r e^{i \phi}\right)^2 \implies r^2 = 2\,,\;2\phi = \pi/2 + 2k\pi$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose one difficulty some will encounter here is how to factor $z^2-2i.$

You can observe that $$2i = 2(\cos90^\circ + i\sin90^\circ),$$ and therefore $$\pm\sqrt{2i\,} = \pm\sqrt 2(\cos45^\circ + i\sin45^\circ) = \pm \sqrt 2\left( \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} + i \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \right) = \pm( 1+i).$$

Therefore $z^2 - 2i = \Big(z - (1+i)\Big)\Big( z+ ( 1+i)\Big).$

For the rest, if you know how to do other sorts of arithmetic with complex numbers, just proceed as with real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=1+i$, then $ a^2=2i$.

Decomposing $ \displaystyle \frac{1}{z^{2}-2 i} \equiv \frac{A}{z-a}+\frac{B}{z+a}$  yields$$1 \equiv A(z+a)+B(z-a).
$$

Putting $z=a$ yields $ \displaystyle A=\frac{1}{2 a}=\frac{1-i}{4}.$

Putting $ \displaystyle z=-a$ yields $ \displaystyle B=-\frac{1}{2 a}=-\frac{1-i}{4}.$

Now we can conclude that
$$ \frac{1}{z^{2}-2 i}=\frac{1-i}{4(z-1-i)}-\frac{1-i}{4(z+1+i)}.
$$